# building extendable chainable modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a node.js module where I can extend my module on load (like jquery plugins), and have the functions of those plugins chainable.

From what I understand, if I return an updated object from my module, they should be chainable. (I got that from here http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/)

So far, this is what I've got, and I'm not sure entirely where I've gone wrong.

I build my object with

```
 var my_obj = new MyObj(json_obj);
    var modules = ['get_and_set']; // an array for plugins to be included

    MyObj.prototype.core_function = function(){
    // does something and returns 
    }

    if(modules){
      modules.forEach(function(module){
       MyObj.prototype = require(module);
    });
    }

   // then I export my module
 module.exports = my_obj(json_file);
```

then, in my child module, I export the named functions I'm trying to add to my module.

```
module.exports.get = function(){
     return this.value;
}

module.exports.set = function(x){ 
      this.value=x;
      return this;
}
```

When I run my tests, node spits out errors saying `has no method get` or `has no method set`.

Is there a nicer way for me to extend MyObj without manually defining what methods will be in the included from the exported module? am I doing the chaining right?